# What was this user trying to hack and is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, xss

I randomly got on my website today and happened to notice this:

```
String.fromCharCode(67, 79, 78, 67, 65, 84, 95, 87, 83, 40, 67, 72, 65, 82, 40, 51, 50, 44, 53, 56, 44, 51, 50, 41, 44, 117, 115, 101, 114, 40, 41, 44, 100, 97, 116, 97, 98, 97, 115, 101, 40, 41, 44, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 40, 41, 41)
```

Someone tried entering a string. Confused, I looked it up and found out I can translate it.

```
CONCAT_WS(CHAR(32,58,32),user(),database(),version())
```

What does this information reveal and can you actually get into a database from javascript?

Comment: He was attempting to SQL inject you. Javascript itself can't touch your DB, but that translated string can do some things (it would concatenate a string using those functions).

Comment: If there is a javascript library with drivers and the database server doesn't reject remote connections, sure, one might be able to get into a database from javascript. But I've never heard of a javascript db library.

Comment: it's an sql injection attack attempt. it'd reveal details about your DB and the account used to connect to it. e.g. `root: mysql : 5.5.56`

Comment: FYI: `CHAR(32,58,32)` translates to `' : '`.

Comment: can you explain where you noticed this code?

Comment: Where did you find this?  I think that's possibly a more important question, since you could have someone with access to your web server.

Comment: I noticed this code where on a chat form where people can talk to other users. I was wondering, could this actually get an entire database or what?

Comment: This itself wouldn't make an intruder to get inside your db. As pointed by Marc, this would give - maybe - valuable informations for the attacker, although. With more informations, more windows get open for exploitment. @RichardSedanna

Comment: Very scary stuff. I'm guessing what prevented this going through was htmlspecialchars?

Comment: htmlspecialchars would not prevent this

Comment: What would prevent against this? Are you sure htmlspecialchars wouldn't?

Comment: to know what prevented it, we'd need to see how you're getting from javascript to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is important to recognize that your website will likely be under attack no matter how secure you make it. That's why we make things secure, right? First rule is don't panic!

Just because someone searches for `http://example.com/q=<script>alert('xss')</script>` doesn't mean you are vulnerable to cross site scripting. They are checking to see if you are.

Just because someone tries to make their username `' OR 1=1--` doesn't mean you have a SQL injection vulnerability.

The person/bot who entered this text was probing to see if you were vulnerable to SQL injection. `CONCAT_WS(CHAR(32,58,32),user(),database(),version())` is just an attempt at blind SQL injection to see if they can insert something and get the database to return data. This information is not particularly valuable, but the fact that they can get it would be. The next thing to do would be to modify or dump your database (or maybe even just tell you about the vulnerability) depending on their motives.

We can't really tell you if you are vulnerable from anything just from the information given. Just that someone was attempting to probe your site for vulnerabilities, which happens all the time to many, many people.

So basically, the user was testing to see if you were vulnerable (not necessarily malicious), but we can't tell you if your system is weak to this. It would depend on how you handled that string.

Answer (score 0):

*With the help of the comments from Zachrip and Marc B:*

> He was attempting to SQL inject you. Javascript itself can't touch
>   your DB, but that translated string can do some things (it would
>   concatenate a string using those functions). –  Zachrip
>
> it's an sql injection attack attempt. it'd reveal details about your
>   DB and the account used to connect to it. e.g. `root: mysql : 5.5.56` – 
>   Marc B

(pointed by user Rocket Hazmat, `CHAR(32,58,32)` translates to `' : '`)

And for your concern (very good concern):

This itself wouldn't make an intruder able to get inside your db. This would give - maybe/probably - valuable informations for the attacker, although. With more information, more windows get open for exploitment.

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted you, but in order for "CONCAT_WS(CHAR(32,58,32),user(),database(),version())" to run, wouldn't they need to insert it into a database? How would Javascript be able to return a query like that?

Comment: @RichardSedanna it wouldn't. But with tons of ways (I'm not updated anymore, sorry :() to SQL inject **using** JS, I'm pretty sure it is possible. And don't worry about the downvote, thanks :)